# How to create user account from script non-interactively without the password being seen?

Tags: debian, useradd

The `man` page for `useradd` says

http://linux.die.net/man/8/adduser

> -p, --password PASSWORD The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password. Note: This option is
>   not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be
>   visible by users listing the processes.
>
> You should make sure the password respects the system's password
>   policy.

But there doesn't seem to be any other way to create an account. Also, it says the default is to disable the password - what does that mean?

I am using Debian Wheezy

Answer (score 1):

taken from this script https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/6321547

There's a great language called expect that interacts with programs. Here's what you're looking for. You can always modify this to pull username and password from an external source.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

set user "username"
set password "password"

send "useradd -m $user\r"

# Expect prompt
expect "$"

# Set password
send "passwd $user\r"

# Expect password prompt and send pass
expect "ass"
send "$password\r"

# Expect confirm
expect "ass"
send "$password\r"
```